# v-bind not working for primevue InputMask inside Vee Validate Form and Field

Tags: vuejs3, yup, vee-validate, input-mask, primevue

I'm trying to create a reusable component that can validate using vee-validate and yup. But when i use v-bind on InputMask it does not change the value for the field.

I'm using primevue inputmask (https://primevue.org/inputmask/)

Component: MyInputTelefone.vue

```
<template>
    <Field :name="fieldName" v-slot="{ field, errorMessage }">
        <label :for="field">{{ label }}:</label>
        <InputMask :id="field.name"  v-bind="field"
            class="w-100" mask="(99) 9 9999-9999" placeholder="(99) 99999-9999" :class="{ 'p-invalid': errorMessage }" />
        <small v-show="errorMessage" class="p-error">{{ errorMessage }}</small>
    </Field>
</template>
<script>
import { Field } from 'vee-validate'
export default {
    components: {
        Field
    },
    props: {
        fieldName: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        icon: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: ''
        },
        label: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        inputType: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: 'text'
        }
    }

}
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

MyForm.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Form :initial-values="initialValue" @submit="onSubmit" :validation-schema="pfSchema" v-slot="{ errors, values }">
            <MyInputTelefone fieldName="telefone" label="Telefone" />
            <Button label="SUBMIT" class="w-100" type="submit" />
            <pre>
                {{ values }}
            </pre>
        </Form>

    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { Form } from 'vee-validate'
import * as yup from 'yup'
import MyInputTelefone from '@/components/MyInputTelefone.vue'

const initialValue = {
    telefone: ""
}

export default {
    components: {
        Form,
        MyInputTelefone
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit(values, actions) {
            console.log("onSubmit", values)
        }
    },
    data() {
        const pfSchema = yup.object({
            telefone: yup.string().required(),
        })

        return {
            pfSchema
        }
    }

}
</script>
<style ></style>
```

When i type in the InputMask nothing happens. It doesn't change the value on the form neither in the input mask.

[image: can't type in the inputmask]

Answer (score 0):

Component: MyInputTelefone.vue

add v-model="formValues[field.name]" and the new prop formValues

```
<template>
    <Field :name="fieldName" v-slot="{ field, errorMessage }">
        <label :for="field.name">{{ label }}:</label>
        <InputMask :id="field.name" class="w-100" :name="field.name" v-bind="field" v-model="formValues[field.name]" mask="(99) 9 9999-9999"
            placeholder="(99) 99999-9999" :class="{ 'p-invalid': errorMessage }" />
        <small v-show="errorMessage" class="p-error">{{ errorMessage }}</small>
    </Field>
</template>
<script>
import { Field } from 'vee-validate'
export default {
    components: {
        Field
    },
    props: {
        fieldName: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        icon: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: ''
        },
        label: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        inputType: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: 'text'
        },
        formValues: {
            required: true
        }

    }

}
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

MyForm.vue

add the property formValues

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Form :initial-values="initialValue" @submit="onSubmit" :validation-schema="pfSchema" v-slot="{ errors, values }">
            <MyInputTelefone fieldName="telefone" label="Telefone" :formValues="values"/>
            <Button label="SUBMIT" class="w-100" type="submit" />
            <pre>
                {{ values }}
            </pre>
        </Form>

    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { Form } from 'vee-validate'
import * as yup from 'yup'
import MyInputTelefone from '@/components/MyInputTelefone.vue'

const initialValue = {
    telefone: ""
}

export default {
    components: {
        Form,
        MyInputTelefone
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit(values, actions) {
            console.log("onSubmit", values)
        }
    },
    data() {
        const pfSchema = yup.object({
            telefone: yup.string().required(),
        })

        return {
            pfSchema
        }
    }

}
</script>
<style ></style>
```